# Difference between cordova build --debug and --release

Tags: android, cordova

I read the [cordova CLI documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#cordova-build-command) and searched in Google but the info is very scarce.

The docs say:

> --debug   Perform a debug build. This typically translates to debug mode for the underlying platform being built.
> --release   Perform a release build. This typically translates to release mode for the underlying platform being built.

What exactly are the differences between `--debug` and `--release`? How that translates differently for example for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apk built via debug will be chrome inspect-able while the release won't be. Google Play requires release builds. Also with the `--release -- --packageType=bundle` flag you generates a bundle (instead of apk) for Google Play store.

Furthermore the release build needs to be signed with your certificate, whereas the debug not.

Comment: you should add (I just realized now) that the `release` build needs to be signed and debug not